# Как растянуть таблицу чтобы она отображалась по середине экрана?

Tags: html

В качестве обучения прохожу курс со stepik по html и css, на данном этапе я должен был сделать таблицу вот такой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а у меня она получается вот такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**по условиям задачи я не могу пользоваться CSS**

Comment: Прикладывайте код текстом.

Comment: Указывайте ширину ячейки таблицы для верхней строки с заголовком и будет вам счастье без css. http://htmlbook.ru/HTML/TABLE

Comment: `<table width=100%>[...]</table>` может так?

Answer (score 1):

Оформите таблицу таким образом:

```
<p align=center>
<table width=800px>
 ...
</table>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

В теге table указывайте width=ххх px, где ххх любое значение (числовое или процент), также width можно указать конкретно каждой колонке. Если нужно сделать таблицу посередине, но не на всю страницу, указывайте в table  например, width = 80%, но в css указывайте отступы слева и справа через margin left/right